# iOS 5 + iPad 1 + Apple Digital AV Adapter: Video not playing on the TV

Tags: ipad, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video streaming app that has been available since iOS 4.3.  When run on an iPad 1 with iOS versions previous to iOS 5, via an Apple Digital AV Adapter via HDMI, it worked perfectly.  You just plugged it into the TV and it worked.  However, this no longer works on iOS 5. I am aware of the changes with iOS 5 and the various mirroring abilities and support for external display adapters.

It appears that I could support the TV as an external display and add all the necessary code to play the videos using that technology and have them display properly on the TV.  My question is, do I really need to do that?  Is there no way to have it work like it worked prior to iOS 5, without me having to implement all the code for external displays?   BTW, both the native video app and the YouTube app still play video just fine and display the screen on the iPad which says "Video is playing on the TV".  Those apps seem to work just as they did with iOS 4.3 with the AV Adapter.

Comment: I'm having this problem right now.. Did you ever find a solution?